# Error -input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't understand what is wrong i did the same code with the insert and run well

```
Entity obj = new Entity();
.
.
.
obj.DEPID = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDEPID")).Text);
myFactory.UpdateObject(obj);
```

Comment: Well ... obvious answer would be that the content of txtDEPID is not a decimal.

Comment: Referring to "the insert", which is not shown here, won't help anyone figure out what's wrong with "the update" (I guess). Also, if you got an error (exception?), why don't you tell us where exactly it occurred? And since this is UI code, why don't you let us know exactly what text was input into `txtDEPID` when this code failed?

Answer (score 1):

The value that is returned by the

```
((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDEPID")).Text
```

Is not a decimal-like string. It contains some other Special Characters like alphabets etc.

While passing the values, you need to make sure that the values being passed match the values required. Check what is the value of this.

```
txtDEPID.Text;
```

Use it in a MessageBox, to check for the value. I'm sure there is some sort of *non decimal* part in the string. Which is causing the trouble while converting the String to Decimal.

```
MessageBox.Show(txtDEPID.Text);
```